# Lookup on multiple columns with node-restful

Tags: node.js, rest, api, mongoose

I have a couple of problems here.
I am trying out [node-restful](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful). I have a collection something like as follows

```
 {
        "_id": "59de06427f04284a1601e8bd",
        "name": "Thabung",
        "region": "59de03667f04284a1601e58f",
        "__v": 1,
        "branches": [
            {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "_id": "59de070a7f04284a1601e8be",
                "address": {
                    "street": "FairyStreet",
                    "country": "ABC",
                    "city": "BLL",
                    "zip": "123456"
                },
                "customerCodes": [
                    "ccd",
                    "xyz"
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Now, if I pass the query like `apiendpoint/?branches.name=XYZ` it works. However if I try to `apiendpoint/?branches.customerCodes=ccd` it does not match. Note that `branches.customerCodes` is an array

Also I want to match on multiple fields something like

`apiendpoint/?fieldone=XYZ&fieldtwo=abc`, How should I proceed?